# A function for which one-sided limits are zero and infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it possible for a function to have a limit from the left be infinite and the limit from the right be zero, both at the same number?

Comment: What do you mean "both limits are approaching the same number"? Do you mean the same value of $x$ while the one-sided limits for $y$ are $\infty$ and $0$?

Comment: Sure: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac1x,&\text{if }x<0\\0,&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! Yes I mean the same value of x while the one-sided limits for y are infinite and 0?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ will do since

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=e^{+\infty}=+\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=e^{-\infty}=0
$$